# How to prevent tables from being wider than the text width in ConTeXt?

Tags: tables, context, context-mkiv

I have some tables like this:

```
\starttabulate[|l|l|]
    \HL
    \NC Title 1 \NC Title 2 \NC\NR
    \HL
    \NC This is a sentence. \NC This is another sentence. \NC\NR
    \HL
\stoptabulate
```

Sometimes, the sentences are too long, so then the table width becomes very wide.

- How can I make certain that the width of the table never exceeds the width of the available text width?

Comment: Use `p` columns, rather than `l` columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column types of ConTeXt and LaTeX are equal. The column type `l` doesn't allow any breaks and so the table runs out to the margin. To allow line breaks you can use the column type `p`, i.e.

```
\starttabulate[|p|p|]
```

By default, a certain width is used for `p` columns, but the column width can be specified by writing a length in parenthesis after `p`, e.g. `p(4cm)`. See http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/starttabulate for more information about column types.